# Not getting data from Parallax GPS

Tags: arduino, serial, gps, parallax

I am trying to use a Parallax PMB-648 GPS with an Arduino Nano running this code:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

#include <TinyGPS.h>

/* This sample code demonstrates the normal use of a TinyGPS object.
   It requires the use of SoftwareSerial, and assumes that you have a
   4800-baud serial GPS device hooked up on pins 4(rx) and 3(tx).
*/

TinyGPS gps;
SoftwareSerial ss(4, 3);

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  ss.begin(4800);

  Serial.print("Simple TinyGPS library v. "); Serial.println(TinyGPS::library_version());
  Serial.println("by Mikal Hart");
  Serial.println();
}

void loop()
{
  bool newData = false;
  unsigned long chars;
  unsigned short sentences, failed;

  // For one second we parse GPS data and report some key values
  for (unsigned long start = millis(); millis() - start < 1000;)
  {
    while (ss.available())
    {
      char c = ss.read();
      // Serial.write(c); // uncomment this line if you want to see the GPS data flowing
      if (gps.encode(c)) // Did a new valid sentence come in?
        newData = true;
    }
  }

  if (newData)
  {
    float flat, flon;
    unsigned long age;
    gps.f_get_position(&flat, &flon, &age);
    Serial.print("LAT=");
    Serial.print(flat == TinyGPS::GPS_INVALID_F_ANGLE ? 0.0 : flat, 6);
    Serial.print(" LON=");
    Serial.print(flon == TinyGPS::GPS_INVALID_F_ANGLE ? 0.0 : flon, 6);
    Serial.print(" SAT=");
    Serial.print(gps.satellites() == TinyGPS::GPS_INVALID_SATELLITES ? 0 : gps.satellites());
    Serial.print(" PREC=");
    Serial.print(gps.hdop() == TinyGPS::GPS_INVALID_HDOP ? 0 : gps.hdop());
  }

  gps.stats(&chars, &sentences, &failed);
  Serial.print(" CHARS=");
  Serial.print(chars);
  Serial.print(" SENTENCES=");
  Serial.print(sentences);
  Serial.print(" CSUM ERR=");
  Serial.println(failed);
  if (chars == 0)
    Serial.println("** No characters received from GPS: check wiring **");
}
```

I have the red wire on the GPS module going to 5V, the black wire going to GND, the yellow wire to D4, and the blue wire to D3. So far my serial response has just been these lines with steadily progressing character counts and no data:

```
 CHARS=51809 SENTENCES=0 CSUM ERR=0
 CHARS=51990 SENTENCES=0 CSUM ERR=0
 CHARS=52254 SENTENCES=0 CSUM ERR=0
 CHARS=52479 SENTENCES=0 CSUM ERR=0
 CHARS=52642 SENTENCES=0 CSUM ERR=0
 CHARS=52823 SENTENCES=0 CSUM ERR=0
```

Does anyone know what is going wrong or how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was getting data, the GPS just took a ridiculously long time to respond.